# DateTime After 12Pm

Tags: c#, sql

I working on a program that uses shift patterns EG 7pm to 7am 
I have the following statement

```
SELECT MAX(Number)  from LadleControl where Shift = 'Night Shift' and DateTime between @Date1 and @Date2
```

I have set the date time as follows

```
 DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today.AddHours(19).AddMinutes(1);
 DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today.AddHours(30).AddMinutes(59);
```

The problem is when it goes past 12am DateTime.Todays` Date changes and so does the 2 Date parameters.

Is it possible to try and keep the date time to a shift basis 7pm to 7am without it changing at 12am.

I have tried to hardcode in the date and this works but the date will need to change for each shift starts of different days.

Comment: 12pm? Surely you mean 12am? 12pm is lunch time. ;)

Comment: Sorry 12am your correct

Comment: 7am + 12hrs = 7pm same day. 11am + 12hrs = 11pm same day. 7pm + 12hrs = 7am. 11pm + 12hrs = 11am next day. I do not see how "passing 12pm" can make any problems.

Comment: I think `AddDays(1).AddHours(6).AddMinutes(59);` would be clearer than `AddHours(30).AddMinutes(59);`. Are you storing in localised time zone? Hint: The correct answer is *no*.

Comment: Both 12am and 12pm are actually poorly defined. Since the `m` in the acronym is the latin form for midday, and the `a` and `p` indicate before and after, respectively; midday is neither after or before itself, and midnight is equi-distant from the preceding and succeeding middays.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl - if that's a response to my comment, I was trying to point out that both 12am and 12pm are poorly defined (and why), and so hoping that it would prompt the OP to write a clearer question that contains *neither* term. If they mean midnight, they should say midnight.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes AM and PM, like Imperial Measurements, are rubbish. ;)

Comment: @Damien - I misread what you wrote and thought that you describe AM/PM madness (I'm strich 24h'er). After rereading your text next two times, I've noticed that you point out the exact noon/midnight timepoints and the ambiguity between casually used '12am' and '12pm' -- [Wiki:"Confusion 12am/12pm'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight).

Comment: @MatthewWatson - just like me before, you've probably misread him. AM/PM are well defined and 'logical' sans 12am/12pm which are very unfortunate..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl What Damien was saying was that "PM" means "after midday" (literally!) yet "midday" is clearly not "after midday". It's just rubbish semantics, but we all just learn that 12PM means "midday". The OP's original question used "PM" intead of "AM" hence this discussion (he's corrected it now)

Comment: @MatthewWatson - "we all just learn that 12PM means "midday"" - I guess I must have missed that class. I've never been taught to think of 12pm as being midday. I've always been taught that's its ambiguous. And yet we're both UK dwellers. Maybe it's not as universal a convention as you think it is.

Comment: Let's leave what who has said and what meant. AM/PM is still far easier than i.e. [Imperial Units of Length](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/English_length_units_graph.svg) - currently, one of my favorite charts ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood the problem correctly

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime startDate;
DateTime endDate;
if (now.Hour < 7)
    startDate = now.Date.AddDays(-1).AddHours(19).AddMinutes(1);
else
    startDate = now.Date.AddHours(19).AddMinutes(1);

endDate = startDate.AddHours(11).AddMinutes(58);
```

Comment: Please use `DateTime.UtcNow` rather than `Now`. It's quicker, and it's what we should use for storing time data.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann: But the current locale is important in this case, isn't it? Apart from that, i have used a variable so efficiency doesn't matter. However, edited the answer to use `DateTime.UtcNow`. OP can decide what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a "Today", and add 30 hours, you will arrive "tomorrow", so that behaviour is by design.

You might want to create startDate and endDate by using the DateTime constructor, providing year, month, day, hour and minutes and so forth.